# Switching on Strings

Tags: java, string, scala, switch-statement, hashcode

I was curious to see how Java and Scala implement switches on strings:

```java
class Java
{
    public static int java(String s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
        case "foo": return 1;
        case "bar": return 2;
        case "baz": return 3;
        default: return 42;
        }
    }
}
```

```scala
object Scala {
  def scala(s: String): Int = {
    s match {
      case "foo" => 1
      case "bar" => 2
      case "baz" => 3
      case _ => 42
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like Java switches on the hashcode and then does a single string comparison:

```
 0: aload_0       
 1: dup           
 2: astore_1      
 3: invokevirtual #16    // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
 6: lookupswitch  { // 3
           97299: 40
           97307: 52
          101574: 64
         default: 82
    }
40: aload_1       
41: ldc           #22    // String bar
43: invokevirtual #24    // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
46: ifne          78
49: goto          82
52: aload_1       
53: ldc           #28    // String baz
55: invokevirtual #24    // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
58: ifne          80
61: goto          82
64: aload_1       
65: ldc           #30    // String foo
67: invokevirtual #24    // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
70: ifne          76
73: goto          82
76: iconst_1      
77: ireturn       
78: iconst_2      
79: ireturn       
80: iconst_3      
81: ireturn       
82: bipush        42
84: ireturn
```

In contrast, Scala seems to compare against all the cases:

```
 0: aload_1       
 1: astore_2      
 2: ldc           #16    // String foo
 4: aload_2       
 5: invokevirtual #20    // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
 8: ifeq          16
11: iconst_1      
12: istore_3      
13: goto          47
16: ldc           #22    // String bar
18: aload_2       
19: invokevirtual #20    // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
22: ifeq          30
25: iconst_2      
26: istore_3      
27: goto          47
30: ldc           #24    // String baz
32: aload_2       
33: invokevirtual #20    // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
36: ifeq          44
39: iconst_3      
40: istore_3      
41: goto          47
44: bipush        42
46: istore_3      
47: iload_3       
48: ireturn
```

Is it possible to convince Scala to employ the hashcode trick? I would rather prefer an O(1) solution to an O(n) solution. In my real code, I need to compare against 33 possible keywords.

Comment: I don't think Java will do this all the time, what is the guarantee that all the strings given have different hashcodes? This check is probably done in the interpreter (JVM) and only chooses the hashcode solution if all the strings will evaluate to a distinct hash value

Comment: @Smac89 Hash collisions are no problem at all. Java will simply jump to the same place and then do 2 string comparisons instead of 1. Also, the compiler knows all the strings and hence all their hashcodes. There is no need for the JVM to analyze the situation dynamically.

Comment: I'm also curious... is Scala still useful now that Java 8 is out?

Comment: @TritonMan Java 7 + Lambdas != Scala. Scala has still so much more to offer over Java 8. Case classes and pattern matching come to mind. You can find exhaustive laundry lists of features via Google ;)

Comment: @fredoverflow And non-abstract methods in traits! Oh wait, Java 8 has that too. :)

Comment: @райтфолд function currying is something I haven't seen in Java 8 (yet).

Comment: A side note: The Scala match/case construct is far more powerful than the (recently introduced) switch/case on Strings in Java. It might either be that the Scala people do/did not see such a great gain-to-effort ratio of figuring out an optimized byte code for the - so to say - *very* special case where all `case`s of a `match` are strings.

Comment: It's worth mentioning which scala and java versions you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely it seems that this case is a lack of optimization from the Scala compiler. Sure, the `match` construct is much (much much) powerful than the switch/case in Java, and it is a lot harder to optimize it, but it could detect these special cases in which a simple hash comparison would apply.

Also, I don't think this case will show many times in idiomatic Scala, because you always match with case classes that have some meaning apart from having different value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're thinking about Scala from a Java point of view (I think you're also prematurely optimizing, but hey).

I would think that the solution you want is to instead memoize your mapping.
You've got a function that maps from String -> Int, right? So do this:

```
class Memoize1[-T, +R](f: T => R) extends (T => R) {
  import scala.collection.mutable
  private[this] val vals = mutable.Map.empty[T, R]

  def apply(x: T): R = {
    if (vals.contains(x)) {
      vals(x)
    }
    else {
      val y = f(x)
      vals += ((x, y))
      y
    }
  }
}

object Memoize1 {
  def apply[T, R](f: T => R) = new Memoize1(f)
}
```

(this memoizing code is taken from [here](https://michid.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/function_mem/).

Then you can memoize your code like this:

```
object Scala {
  def scala(s: String): Int = {
    s match {
      case "foo" => 1
      case "bar" => 2
      case "baz" => 3
      case _ => 42
    }
  }

  val memoed = Memoize1(Scala.scala)

  val n = memoed("foo")
}
```

Tada! Now you're doing hash value comparisons.  Although I will add that most memoization examples (this one included) are toys and will not survive most use cases. Real-world [memoization should include an upper limit](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2010/07/26/limit-your-memoization-please.aspx) to the amount you're willing to cache, and in the case of your code where you have a tiny number of possible valid cases and a huge number of invalid cases, I would consider making a general class that pre-builds the map and has a specialized lookup that says, "in my cache, you win, not in my cache, default." which can be done very easily by tweaking the memoizer to take a `List` of input to precache and change the "not-in-cache" code to return a default.

Comment: Yeah... or I could just put the string switch in a `.java` file and use it from Scala :)

Comment: Sincerely, as much as I do like memoization, I don't think it is a valuable answer in this case...

Answer (score 2):

This problem inspired me to learn about Scala macros, and I might as well share my solution.

Here is how I use the macro:

```
switch(s, 42, "foo", "bar", "baz")
```

The associated values are counted up automatically. If this is not what you want, you can change the implementation to accept `ArrowAssoc`s instead, but this was way too complicated for me.

And here is how the macro is implemented:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object StringSwitch {

  def switch(value: String, default: Long, cases: String*): Long =
    macro switchImpl

  def switchImpl(c: Context)(value: c.Expr[String], default: c.Expr[Long],
                             cases: c.Expr[String]*): c.Expr[Long] = {
    import c.universe._

    val buf = new ListBuffer[CaseDef]
    var i = 0
    for (x <- cases) {
      x match {
        case Expr(Literal(Constant(y))) =>
          i += 1
          buf += cq"${y.hashCode} => if ($x.equals($value)) $i else $default"

        case _ => throw new AssertionError("string literal expected")
      }
    }
    buf += cq"_ => $default"

    c.Expr(Match(q"$value.hashCode", buf.toList))
  }
}
```

Note that this solution does not handle hash collisions. Since the particular strings I care about in my actual problem do not collide, I didn't cross that particular bridge yet.